# Sweet Alert not waiting until user clicks ok

Tags: jquery, symfony, sweetalert

I am using SweetAlert with Symfony and I want the user to confirm before completing a delete action.

What's happening is when the user clicks the delete button the SweetAlert pops up, then disappears right away and the item was deleted.

I do not want the item deleted until the user clicks ok from the SweetAlert pop up.

Here is my setup.

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this Job Title!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false
        }, function (isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm){
                swal("Deleted!", "Job Title has been deleted.", "success");
            } else {
                swal("Cancelled", "Job Title was not deleted.", "error");
            }
        });
    };
```

HTML:

```
<a href="{{ path('setup_jobtitles_delete', {'id': jobTitle.id}) }}" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-white" data-toggle="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">
    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</a>
```

How do I make the delete action wait until the user clicks ok?

EDIT: I ended up using `$.post` and moved the `href` to a `data-` like this:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="myFunction(this)" data-url="{{ path('setup_jobtitles_delete', {'id': jobTitle.id}) }}" class="btn btn-white" data-toggle="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">
                                                                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                                            </a>
function myFunction(btn) {
        var url = $(btn).data('url');
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this Job Title!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        }, function () {
             $.post(url, function(){
                swal("Deleted!", "Job Title has been deleted.", "success");
                $(btn).parents('tr').remove();
             });
        });
    };
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with Symfony. You have to prevent default browser behaviour (by returning false onclick i.e.)

Comment: So I changed my onclick to this: `myFunction(); return false;` and it is not deleting anything now. I am able to click ok, but it does not delete.

Comment: Where you read that sweetalert allow you to delete anything? It's just simple js alert function nice looking wrapper. You can add ajax call to your `isConfirm` function to delete action in your Symfony backend.

Comment: @malcolm i'm also having issue with using ajax. The delete buttons are coming from a php foreach and for some reason it will not return the correct URL from the anchor I clicked on.

Comment: js have nothing to php foreach, it read generated html. There must be a reason, you have to find it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do as following:

```
<a href="/delete/me" class="confirm" data-title="Want to delete this?" data-type="warning">Click me</a>

<a href="/edit/me" class="confirm" data-title="Info image" data-type="info">Click me</a>
```

and JS part, require jquery loaded

```
$(function() {
    $('a.confirm').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var tthis = $(this);
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: $(this).data('title'),
                type: $(this).data('type'),
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: "Yes",
                cancelButtonText: "No",
            }, function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    document.location.href = tthis.attr('href');
                }
            });
        });
});
```

To wait user confirm you must cancel link action with `e.preventDefault();`

then manually go to link once user confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

you can set alert in controller like this.

```
public function index()    //normal index
{
    return view('hello.index');
}

public function index_alert($message)    //index with alert
{   
    return redirect()->route('hello.index')->with('success', $message);;
}
```

and set your ajax/javascript go to the "alert" route.

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success:function(data){   
    window.location.href = "index/alert/"+data.message;
  }
});
```

and add this route in web.php

```
Route::get('index/alert/{message}', 'YourController@index_alert');
```

Answer (score -1):

A much easier solution is to add the function directly in the `onclick` like so:

```
<a href="{{ path('setup_jobtitles_delete', {'id': jobTitle.id}) }}"
    onclick="return confirm('are u sure?')" class="btn btn-white"
    data-toggle="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">
    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</a>
```

I use this and it will only go to the route if you click ok.
It's simple --> Keep your code simple.

EDIT #2

What if you change your function like so:

```
function myFunction() {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this Job Title!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }, function () {
        swal("Deleted!", "Job Title has been deleted.", "success");
    });
};
```

Any difference?

Comment: Yes, this works for me, but I am using SweetAlert. I don't want to use the standard JS alert.

Comment: I'm new to SweetAlert. I can see why you might want to use it. Try the EDIT #2 change I added.

Comment: Still deletes right away and closes the pop up immediately. Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Have you used your browser tools to set a javascript breakpoint and single step through the code to see that it's actually getting to that function and what is happening exactly? I suspect it's something else!